# SQL Server User create script Password description

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, encryption

Below is my create script of user

```
CREATE LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD=N'ô/PDM643¸}''8%õ''f;âw¡ÈS'
```

Can you tell me this password please?

Comment: `SELECT CAST(N'ô/PDM643¸}''8%õ''f;âw¡ÈS AS CHAR);` ?

Comment: Are you trying to find out the password for **sa** by scripting off the `CREATE` statement?

Comment: Assuming your missing a final `'` Its the result of `select 'ô/PDM643¸}''8%õ''f;âw¡ÈS'`

Comment: single quote was missing. It is updated now

Comment: So, you lost your sa password?  Reinstall Windows.  : )

Comment: As a password, that string is stored correctly; `select password_hash from Sys.sql_logins where name='sa'`, `select pwdcompare(N'ô/PDM643¸}''8%õ''f;âw¡ÈS', paste-hash-here)` the result will be `1` if they match & indeed ot works for me as a password in SSMS

Answer (score 0):

I would say its **[** ô/PDM643¸}'8%õ'f;âw¡ÈS **]**.

```
select N'ô/PDM643¸}''8%õ''f;âw¡ÈS'
```

Double quotes like: '' makes just one ' at the end.

And shouldn't forget that N'somestirng' not really the same as 'somestring'.

- N'somestirng' - stores 2 bytes/char
- 'somestirng' - stores 1 bytes/char

So if there is some special characters like in this case- it makes difference.

Answer (score 0):

That password is a one way hash of the original password entered.  No one here is going to be able to decrypt it without generating a rainbow table based on the way it was hashed.

So, if you've lost the password then you need to login into the machine using the administrator account and change it.

If you're just trying to hack a sql server... well, I don't think anyone needs to give you more advice.